# use_frameworks! Cocoapods, can't find header file for non-cocoapods framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using Cocoapods in my project, but I also want to use frameworks that are not managed by Cocoapods. I recently tried to switch to frameworks using the `use_frameworks!` command in my podfile, but the result is that the build fails because it can't find a header from my third-party framework. In the xcconfig file for my project, I have `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/vendor`, which worked in the past (vendor being where the .framework file is stored).

I don't know much about this topic; my attempt at solving this was to add a `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` setting to the xcconfig file with the same settings as the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`, which did not solve the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: upon further investigation into the problem I think I better understand what is causing this behavior, though I'm no closer to a resolution. The Xcconfig configuration I'm using is set up approximately like this for the debug scheme:

- Pods-ProjectName.debug.xcconfig -- the CocoaPods created xcconfig file for the project. Contents are roughly as follows:

`FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) '@executable_path/Frameworks' '@loader_path/Frameworks'
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -iquote "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH/x.framework/Headers" -iquote "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH/y.framework/Headers" -iquote "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH/z.framework/Headers" -iquote "$PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH/a.framework/Headers"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -framework "x" -framework "y" -framework "z" -framework "a"
OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS = $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)
PODS_FRAMEWORK_BUILD_PATH = $(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/Pods-ProjectName
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods`

- ProjectName.xcconfig - contents are as follows:

`APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY = YES
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/vendor
WARNING_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -include "$(SOURCE_ROOT)/ProjectName/ProjectNameVersion.h"
INFOPLIST_FILE = ProjectName/Info.plist
PRODUCT_NAME = ProjectName
SKIP_INSTALL = YES`

- ProjectNameDebug.xcconfig - includes both of the prior xcconfig files, is the project's xcconfig file. In case it matters, here's the contents:
  `#include "ProjectName.xcconfig"
  <h1>include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName.debug.xcconfig"`

The thing is, what I'm actually seeing when I open the xcporoject file and go to Build Settings->Framework Search Paths is `bulid/Debug-iphoneos/Pods-ProjectName`. So somehow my vendor search path is getting overwritten.

Apologies for the formatting, SO didn't want to highlight this stuff as code, and in some cases even tried to make it bold...